# Executing Curl inside an ECS container fails

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ecs

I have an existing spring boot application deployed in an ECS container and I am trying to execute a Curl on one of the endpoints and the request simply times out.

**Deployment Details :**

- I have a spring boot application deployed as a task in an ECS(EC2)
  cluster.
- The cluster is configured with an AutoScalingGroup
  (MaxCapacity :
- NetworkMode is set to 'awsvpc'.
- TaskDefinition
  does not have any explicit health check defined. However the webapp
  has an unsecured "/healthz" API path that simply returns HTTP status
  200.All other URL paths are  protected with spring-security.

Task deployment is successful. i.e. no errors in logs.
Default docker health check indicates everything is fine as long as the main process(i.e. tomcat server) is working.

**Problem :**

If I connect to the EC2 instance (running ECSOptmized Amazon linux 2), and execute a simple Curl, the request times out after about 2 minutes.

Since I am using 'awsvpc' network mode, I have 2 ENIs attached to my EC2 instance.

If I do a Curl using the primary private IP address, the request terminates immediately.

```
sh-4.2$ curl -vvv http://localhost:8085/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8085...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8085 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying [::1]:8085...
* connect to ::1 port 8085 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8085 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8085 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

However, if I do a Curl using the task ENI IP address, the request times out after 2 minutes.

```
sh-4.2$ curl -vvv http://10.0.1.95:8085/
*   Trying 10.0.1.95:8085...
* connect to 10.0.1.95 port 8085 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.0.1.95 port 8085 after 129583 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.0.1.95 port 8085 after 129583 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I have seen some other stackoverflow threads pointing out to verify internet connectivity.
With regards to it, the task is deployed in a private subnet with NAT Gateway. It has outbound connectivty, but no inbound connectivty outside of VPC.
Security Groups have been configured to be wide-open to eliminate any networking issues.(at least for dev testing).

Any idea why Curl from inside the container fails ?

Updating Task Definition used :

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "boot-app-web-container",
            "image": "687xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cdkbootapp:latest",
            "cpu": 1024,
            "memory": 2048,
            "memoryReservation": 2048,
            "links": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "bootwebapp",
                    "containerPort": 8085,
                    "hostPort": 8085,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "command": [],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "DB_ENDPOINT_URL",
                    "value": "dev-boot-app-db.xxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DB_PORT",
                    "value": "3306"
                },
                {
                    "name": "COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET",
                    "value": "1mhfohg82arcdv0mmrt97upaittj1db2eilhfpxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DB_NAME",
                    "value": "bootappdb"
                },
                {
                    "name": "COGNITO_CLIENT_ID",
                    "value": "29ik1ommu2tlm7gxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "name": "COGNITO_ISSUER_URL",
                    "value": "https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ap-south-1_LXeqQWgik"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DB_PASSWORD",
                    "value": "dQoTxxxxxxxx"
                }
            ],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "secrets": [],
            "startTimeout": 120,
            "stopTimeout": 60,
            "dnsServers": [],
            "dnsSearchDomains": [],
            "extraHosts": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "ulimits": [],
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-datetime-format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z",
                    "awslogs-group": "dev-boot-app-log-group",
                    "awslogs-region": "ap-south-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "boot-web-app-ecs-stream",
                    "mode": "non-blocking"
                },
                "secretOptions": []
            },
            "healthCheck": {
                "command": [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "curl -f http://localhost:8085/healthz || exit 1"
                ],
                "interval": 5,
                "timeout": 3,
                "retries": 3,
                "startPeriod": 30
            },
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "boot-app-ecs-tasks",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::687842843974:role/bootappEcsTaskRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::687842843974:role/bootappEcsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 31,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.28"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.30"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-ordering"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
}
```

**UPDATE :**
In spite of the the 'curl' failure, integration of ECS service with ALB(Load balancer) seems to be working like a charm.A running task is indeed registered as a 'healthy' target to the ALB target group and I am able to successfully hit the SpringBoot application's URLs via the load-balancer.

Comment: Could you share what are you retrieving with CURL?

Comment: Pretty much nothing, expect Http status 200 (OK).

    @GetMapping("/healthz")
    public ResponseEntity<?> healthz() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

Comment: We need to understand the target of the curl including its location and port to give a recommendation

Comment: Just updated the question with task definition. As I said earlier, I am hitting the health endpoint with CURL and it doesn't return anything expect HTTP 200.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `awsvpc` networking mode, which gives each task its own dedicated network interface, and you are connecting to the EC2 instance, instead of to the container itself.

The host has a network interface for itself, and the container has its own dedicated network interface. The two network interfaces are different from each other. Therefore `localhost` on the host machine is not the same as `localhost` inside of the container.

> I do a Curl using the task ENI IP address, the request times out after 2 minutes.

Connecting to the IP address of the task should work because you are using the EC2 host's network interface to talk to the task's network interface.

The fact that the connection times out means you need to fix your security groups. The security group of the task needs to accept inbound traffic from the security group of the EC2 instance if you wish to talk from the EC2 hosts network interface to the tasks network interface.

Another thing that would work would be using Amazon ECS Exec to get a shell inside of your running container. Inside of the container you will find that `localhost` resolves to the local container you are inside of.

So long story short `localhost` on the EC2 host is different from `localhost` inside of the container, and the EC2 host can have a different network security group from the tasks running on the host. Security groups need to be authorized to talk to each other, otherwise you will just see a timeout or connection refused.